# How to check list files scanned by intellisense ? How to deactivate it for generated files ?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I am working with Visual Studio, on a C++/Qt project with generated moc files.  I have read in the bottom blue task output that the moc files are scanned.

The moc files are part of the solution, as the qmake is done and then the visual studio project file is generated.
 So the option

> Disable Implicit Files

would not help

I would like to not scan those files as it could help in responsiveness.